# React Navigation Hot reload not working

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux, react-navigation

I started to refactor my entire react native navigation with `react-navigation` and now its working fine, but only thing is now app doesn't support for hot reloading. Every time I save a file that related to route. It give me an hot reload error: `hot.acceptCallback is not a function`. Please reply me, who has fixed this issue already.

** navigation-reducer.js

```
import AppNavigator from '../RouteConfigs';

const initialState = AppNavigator.router.getStateForAction(AppNavigator.router.getActionForPathAndParams('Startup'));

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
  const nextState = AppNavigator.router.getStateForAction(action, state);

  return nextState || state;
};
```

Comment: Running into the same thing right now, have you found a solution?

Comment: your root component should not be a functional component, It should extends `react.component` 
https://gist.github.com/iswanj/5b8371d707a235dfc030cdcb2ce7add7